# Serving LESS, Javascript, and static resources from the same location in Java Play

Tags: java, angularjs, playframework, less, playframework-2.2

### Motivation

I am currently working on an Java Play app that uses Angular.js. At present, I am trying to reorganize my public folder based on feature. For example, all the Javascript, template files, etc. associated with one component would be placed inside a single folder, like so:

```
public
    directives
        component-1
            component-1.template.html
            component-1.js
        component-2
            component-1.template.html
            component-2.js
    scripts
        app.js
    stylesheets
        main.css
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same thing with my CSS and split the selectors like so:

```
public
    directives
        component-1
            component-1.template.html
            component-1.js
            component-1.less
        component-2
            component-1.template.html
            component-2.js
            component-2.less
    scripts
        app.js
    stylesheets
        main.less
```

Ideally, `main.less` should contain minimal to no CSS and only import `component-1.less` and  `component-2.less`.

---

### The problem

However, when I tried to do this, Play doesn't appear to compile my less files. According to the documentation, it appears that Play will only compile less files inside `app/assets`.

So, I tried moving the contents of my `public` folder to `app/assets`. Play successfully detected and compiled my less files, and moved the resulting CSS and Javascript to the public folder, but did not move my template html files.

I also tried moving everything back to the public folder and compiling the less files from there, but Play either threw exceptions or ignored the less files altogether, depending on my configuration.

---

### My question

So essentially, if I try placing the files in the `app/assets` folder, the `.html` template files are ignored. If I try placing the files in `public`, then the `.less` files will fail.

Obviously, I could split the just put the less files in `assets` and the other two files in `public`, but then that defeats the purpose of keeping related files together.

So, I suppose I have three questions. I don't need all of them answered -- having just one answered would be sufficient to solve the problem I'm having. I don't really care if I use `public` or `app/assets` -- I just want to keep the files together.

1. Is it possible to build `.less` files which are contained inside the public folder instead of `apps/assets`?
2. Is it possible to configure Play to stop ignoring `.html` files inside `app/assets`?
3. Is there some other way to achieve the directory structure I'm looking for?

---

Here's my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "my-project"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % "1.14.4"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings


def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = (
  (base / "public" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings ++ lesscSettings

lessEntryPoints := Nil

lesscEntryPoints in Compile <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints)

lesscOptions in Compile := Seq("--yui-compress", "--verbose")
```

I'm currently using the [`play-lessc`](https://github.com/jmparsons/play-lessc) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you settings won't work i wonder what the purpose of `lesscEntryPoints` is. I also wonder if your question should be tagged with Less.

play-lessc allows you to set the compiler options (http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage). These options include   `--include-path=PATHS  Set include paths. Separated by :. Use ; on Windows.` when you set the `include-path` to `/public/`, you can do `@import "stylesheets/project.less";` in "apps/assets/main.less" and `@import "directives/component-1/component-1.less";` in `stylesheets/project.less` and so on